# Cropping with ImageMagick always results in 1x1 images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to crop an image into a bunch of 256x256 tiles (with the right-most and bottom-most images less than 256 pixels due to the remainders), but ImageMagick always generates images that are 1x1.

I use this command (Windows 7 command prompt):

```
convert WBS.png -crop 256x256 +repage +adjoin output\WBS_%02d.jpg
```

After cropping the following message is displayed:

```
convert: geometry does not contain image `WBS.png' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/589.
```

After cropping, the output folder contains 1634 jpg files, all of which are 1 x 1 pixel. The source image is 7218x7650.

Suggestions? I'm sure I'm making some blatant mistake, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if the origin of the image is not at 0,0. In that case, using `+repage` before processing the image should do the trick, i.e.

```
convert WBS.png +repage -crop 256x256 +repage +adjoin output\WBS_%02d.jpg
```

See also the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) of the `-crop` option.

Comment: The additional repage did it. Thanks, SMeyer.